# Saving gt table as PNG without phantomjs

Tags: r, png, gt

I have gt tables I would like to save as PNGs. I tried doing webshot but since I'm using a work secured desktop I don't have the authorization to download phantomJS.

I can still click export as image on RStudio viewer, but I would like to do it in code to avoid the manual work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This issue has been discussed previously (i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66961019/12957340) but I don't know if the solution will apply to your use-case

Comment: Unfortunately the solution in the post you linked uses gtsave which requires webshot and phantomJS.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I don't know of any other way around the problem. knitr::kable, DT, flextable, huxtable, formattable all use webshot to capture html output as a png. Have you tried a non-system-wide method of installing phantom_JS e.g. `webshot::install_phantomjs()`? Or you don't want to use phantom_JS at all because of work policy?

Comment: It's because of work policy. I would need to submit an application to install it and the process would take at least a few weeks with a chance of it being rejected. I am still trying to find ways around it. Other jpeg, png saving methods don't work as well (returns blank). I try to save on export but some of my tables are too large and only parts of the table were captured :(

Answer (score 0):

Use gtsave() and ensure you have chrome downloaded, saving as .png only seems to work with that browser installed.